# Ubuntu will not load up from my USB

Tags: 13.10

I have a Sony Vaio Duo 13 and I am trying to get Ubuntu 13.10 to run on a partition on my Ultrabook but it will not load up from the USB drive.  It goes to the black screen that asks if you just want to Try Ubuntu or if you want to Install it.  I click just to try and it will not load. It acts like it is going to start up but then it just goes to a blank black screen and then I have to a hard restart. It does that when I click install as well.  And I have tried disabling the Secure Install on my computer as well and nothing happens! What do I do?!?

Comment: Which software did you use to make the USB boot-able? Try to make it again, this time with [Starup Disk Creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

How long did you wait before the hard restart?

On my machine it did take a little while to load when running from USB, maybe a minute or so of a black screen before there was an Ubuntu loading icon.

Comment: I left it sitting for 10 minutes and nothing will pop up. The screen is black/off and will not respond..

Comment: You might try booting an older (and stable) version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I just downloaded and tried to install 12.4 and it wont work either. I do not know what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the brightness.  I have a Duo 13 and after booting from the USB the brightness goes to zero.  If you are successful in installing with dual boot please post how you did it.  I had to do a complete recovery after trying to install 13.10 on my Duo 13.